How to apply a dot matrix filter to an image in SwiftUI
I want to achieve the dot matrix style effect that you see on ticker displays in stock exchanges, airports etc. how can i apply this effect to my image in swiftui
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(.bitcoin)
    }
}

This is the effect that i want for my image:


I assume the image background is transparent (not black) and you don’t want black dots on the transparent parts, right?

@Sweeper yes exactly

A metal shader like this could work,
// put this in a file called Shaders.metal
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

[[ stitchable ]] half4 dotMatrix(float2 position, half4 color) {
    if (int(position.x) % 6 < 3 && int(position.y) % 6 < 3) {
        return color;
    } else {
        return half4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}

The idea is to put transparent color at any position where x % 6 >= 3 or y % 6 >= 3. You can adjust the size of the dots and the distance between them by changing 6 and 3.
Usage in SwiftUI:
Image("some image")
    .colorEffect(Shader(
        function: .init(library: .default, name: "dotMatrix"),
        arguments: []
    ))

Output for a simple capsule shape:

For a more circular shape, you can use a condition like this:
if (
    pow((round(position.x / 10) - position.x / 10), 2) +
    pow((round(position.y / 10)  - position.y / 10), 2) < 0.1
)

10 and 0.1 are parameters you can adjust.

What is needed is a way to examine the alpha value of the image at a particular position. Dots can then be drawn in a grid formation at positions where the image is not completely transparent (where alpha > 0).
An ImageRenderer can be used to create a bitmap of the image, which then makes it possible to examine the individual pixels in this way. The example below is based on the answer to SwiftUI - Get pixel color from Image, which shows how to get the color values at a particular pixel position.
The image used here is built using the SF symbol "bitcoinsign", but you should just be able to plug in the image described in the question:
struct ContentView: View {
    let dotSize: CGFloat = 8
    let gapSize: CGFloat = 3
    let imageSize: CGFloat = 220 // a multiple of (dotSize + gapsize)

    private var imageView: some View {
        Image(systemName: "bitcoinsign")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
            .fontWeight(.black)
    }

    var body: some View {
        if let cgi = ImageRenderer(content: imageView).cgImage,
           let dp = cgi.dataProvider,
           let pixelData = dp.data {
            Canvas { ctx, size in
                var path = Path()
                let stepSize = dotSize + gapSize
                var y: CGFloat = stepSize / 2
                while y < size.height {
                    var x: CGFloat = stepSize / 2
                    while x < size.width {
                        let pixelInfo: Int = (cgi.bytesPerRow * Int(y)) + Int(x) * 4
                        if cgi.bitmapInfo.contains(.byteOrderDefault) {
                            let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
                            let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo + 3]) / CGFloat(255)
                            if a > 0 {
                                path.addEllipse(
                                    in: CGRect(
                                        x: x - (dotSize / 2),
                                        y: y - (dotSize / 2),
                                        width: dotSize,
                                        height: dotSize
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        x += stepSize
                    }
                    y += stepSize
                }
                ctx.fill(path, with: .foreground)
            }
            .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
            .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
        }
    }
}



Alternatively, if the image can be converted to a Path then the path function contains can be used to determine if a point for a dot is contained inside the path or not.
The answer to How do I get a Path from an Image( )? provides a way to convert an SF symbol to a path:
struct ContentView: View {
    let dotSize: CGFloat = 8
    let gapSize: CGFloat = 3

    var body: some View {

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/78360887/20386264
        if let cgPath = try? CGPath.contourPath(forSystemName: "bitcoinsign", pointSize: 256, weight: .black) {
            Canvas { ctx, size in
                var path = Path()
                var y: CGFloat = 0
                while y < size.height {
                    var x: CGFloat = 0
                    while x < size.width {
                        if cgPath.contains(CGPoint(x: x, y: y)) {
                            path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: dotSize, height: dotSize))
                        }
                        x += dotSize + gapSize
                    }
                    y += dotSize + gapSize
                }
                ctx.fill(path, with: .foreground)
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
        }
    }
}

This example is taking a slightly lazier approach about which points are examined. Instead of inspecting the point in the middle of a dot, it is inspecting the point in the top-left corner of the frame around a dot. But the result is similar to before:


Answer updated with a different technique (examine the pixels of the image). Doing it this way, you should just be able to plug in your original image.
